# Python - Pandas - date manipulation over series - error

Tags: python, date, pandas

am a Python newbie and stuck at the following problem:

I have created the following series of dates in Pandas:

```
x:

    0  0    2016-09-19
       1    2016-12-19
       2    2016-05-17
       3    2016-08-17
       4    2016-02-17
    ..............
    .............
    ..............
       28   2016-09-13
       29   2016-04-18
       30   2016-05-17
       31   2016-06-17
       32   2016-05-17
       33   2016-06-17
       34   2016-04-18
    dtype: datetime64[ns]
    >>> type(x)
    <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

which I want to modify with my function:

```
def new_date(x):
   todaysdate = time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
   todaysdate = pandas.to_datetime(todaysdate)
   days_diff = x - todaysdate
   days_diff = days_diff.days
   if (days_diff < 14):
      newdate = x + datetime.timedelta(days = 14)
      return(newdate)
   else:
      return(x)
```

This function checks whether a date in x is less than 14 days from today, and if so, it adds 14 days to the date given in x. Here I want to overwrite the date in x itself.

The function works for individual elements in x:

```
>>> new_date(x[4])
Timestamp('2016-03-02 00:00:00')
```

but when looping over x, I am getting this error:

```
>>> for i in range(0, len(x)):
...       x[i] = new_date(x[i])
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in new_date
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1843, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'
```

What I am doing wrong here?
Any pointers much appreciated. Thanks in advance,

Bd

Answer (score 0):

Rather than cluttering the `Series` namespace even more (and even for series that have nothing to do with timedeltas, etc.), a "`dt`" accessor is provided for date and time related attributes.

Instead of `days_diff.days`, do

```
days_diff.dt.days
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works under the assumption that `x[i]`is a `Timestamp` but `x[0]` is actually a `Series` because you have a `MultiIndex`.

Since you don't seem to care about the `MultiIndex` I suggest you just get rid of it.

```
x = x.reset_index(drop=True)
```